# Recipient phone number Whatsapp Business Api error

Tags: facebook-graph-api, whatsapp-cloud-api

I am using the Whatsapp Business API and I am testing my app using their test format, which gives you a test number and you can add your personal phone number to receive the test template. I am correctly receiving the test template from Meta to my phone number, however when I actually test my app, by me sending a message to that test number, this error shows up:

`response: { status: 400, statusText: 'Bad Request', headers: Object [AxiosHeaders] { vary: 'Origin, Accept-Encoding', 'x-business-use-case-usage': '{"199147949938479":[{"type":"whatsapp","call_count":1,"total_cputime":1,"total_time":1,"estimated_time_to_regain_access":0}]}', 'content-type': 'application/json', 'www-authenticate': 'OAuth "Facebook Platform" "invalid_request" "(#131030) Recipient phone number not in allowed list"',`

My phone number is definitely in the allowed list as I am receiving their test template with no problems.
Maybe there is a problem with my area code?
I am from Argentina and my area code is +54. It also has a 9 before the actual phone number.
I tried with and without the 9 and in all possible format. No results.
Any clues what may be?

Comment: I'm getting the same issue here in brazil (+55)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and the solution was to add my number to the allowed phone list without the 9.

Example from Brazil:

- You **should** use `{COUNTRY_CODE}{CITY}{PHONE_NUMBER}` instead of
- `{COUNTRY_CODE}{CITY}9{PHONE_NUMBER}`

In order to verify it you can dig into the response body which usually is at

```js
entry[0].changes[0].value.contacts[0].wa_id
```

or

```js
entry[0].changes[0].value.messages[0].from
```